# Bluebird.js Promise not chaining .then()s

Tags: javascript, socket.io, promise, bluebird

```
socket.on('new video', function(data) {
    console.log("New video")
    var addToCueP = Promise.promisify(addToCue)
    var getCueFromDbP = Promise.promisify(getCueFromDb)

    addToCueP(data.id, socket.nickname)
    .then(function() {
        return getCueFromDbP();
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Emit change video")
        io.sockets.emit('change video', {id: data.id, title: data.title, nick: socket.nickname});
    })          
});
```

I am using Bluebird for promises but I'm having issues, the addToCue function gets called but the other functions after for example the getCuefromDb and the Socket emitter isnt getting triggered, does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong?

**addToCue()**

```
var addToCue = function(id, user) {
console.log("Add to cue")
var video = new Video();
video.id = id;
video.user = user;
video.save(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        return true
    }
});
}
```

**getCueFromDb()**

```
var getCueFromDb = function(callback) {
Video.find({}).exec(function(err, videos) {
        if (err) {
            return err;
        }
        if (videos.length) {
            cue = []; // empty array
            videos.forEach(function(video) {
                cue.push(video.id) // push all the videos from db into cue array
            });
            io.sockets.emit('send cue', {cue: cue});
            console.log("getCueFromDb", cue)
            if (callback) {
                callback();
                return
            }
            else {
                return
            }
        }
        else {
            cue = [];
            io.sockets.emit('send cue', {cue: cue});
            console.log("getCueFromDb (no videos)", cue)
            if (callback)
                callback()
            else
                return
        }
})
}
```

Comment: what are the signatures of `addToCue()` and `getCueFromDb()`? And if you're already working with Promises, why do you have to promisify these functions? Why don't they return Promises?

Comment: They're just normal functions but I want them to execute in this order I thought this was the correct way to go about it instead of callbacks am I wrong?

Comment: you are not handling errors, from what you described one possible case is that `addToCueP` throw or reject with an error

Comment: I would agree with preferring Promises over callbacks. But [this is the code](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/src/promisify.js) to promisify something. Ain't it simpler to just return a Promise than letting this engine guess how to promisify your function? But besides that, you didn't answer the question about the actual signatures of `addToCue()` and `getCueFromDb()`.

Comment: Updated the question with the addToCue() and getCueFromDb() functions, starting to think promisify isn't what I'm looking for experimenting with join Bluebird method at the moment but it's still not executing in the correct order hmm...

Comment: `addToCue` and other function should always return promise othewise it wont' chain. With bluebird, for this purpose you can use `Promise.method` around your entire 2 functions, [see the doc](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.method.html) for reference how to use it.

Comment: Promisify you would use more for `Video.exec` method or for library you don't have control on, not needed to use with your own code really

Comment: Mongoose, which you seem to be using, already has [built-in promise support](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/harmony.html) for all async operations, so you probably don't have to promisify anything.

Comment: What you actually should promisify are the `save` and `exec` methods that take asynchronous callbacks. Then use promises yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`addToCue()` does not accept the right types of arguments in order to call `.promisify()` on it- therefore promisify does not work properly with it.

The last argument to `addToCue()` MUST be a callback that is called when the async operation is done and the first argument to that callback must be an error value and the second argument can be a result.

Now, since you control the code to `addToCue()`, you should just change its code to return a promise that is resolved/rejected based on the underlying async operation and not use `.promisify()` at all.

```
var addToCue = function(id, user) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        console.log("Add to cue")
        var video = new Video();
        video.id = id;
        video.user = user;
        video.save(function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `.promisify()` on `video.save()` or `.promisifyAll()` on the Video object.

Or, if your Video interface already supports promises, you can just use it's native support and return that promise.